# TypeScript - Type undefined is not assignable to type ICustomType

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

I'm quite new to TypeScript and trying to understand what is the best way to approach such situation in my code.

I have array of objects that have a custom type in my system and I use `Array.find` method to get one of them. However I receive a compile error saying `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type IConfig`.

Here's the code example -

```
const config: IConfig = CONFIGS.find(({ code }) => code === 'default');
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type IConfig
```

I tried to add `undefined` as possible type but then I get error on the next line which uses this object `Object is possibly 'undefined'`, e.g. -

```
const config: IConfig | undefined = CONFIGS.find(({ code }) => code === 'default');

// Object is possibly 'undefined'
if (config.foo) {
   return 'bar';
}
```

What is the best way to approach such type issues?

Comment: Are you *sure* that a `default` code will exist in `CONFIGS`?

Comment: yes, it's a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find` will return `undefined` if nothing in the array passes the callback test. If you're sure that `default` code exists in the array, then use the non-null assertion operator:

```
const config: IConfig = CONFIGS.find(({ code }) => code === 'default')!;
//                                                                    ^
```

(If you weren't sure if it exists in the array, the warning you see is there to prompt you to explicitly test for if the item exists before trying to access a property on it, otherwise you'll sometimes get a runtime error:

```
const config: IConfig = CONFIGS.find(({ code }) => code === 'default');

if (!config) {
  return 'No match found';
}
if (config.foo) {
   return 'bar';
}
```

)